# Cleanest way to patch a multi-document YAML file in Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

Consider the following multi-document YAML file used to create Kubernetes resources. The file is generated by a third party vendor's API:

```yaml
# VENDOR_GENERATED_YAML.yml
---

---

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: twistlock-secrets
  namespace: twistlock
type: Opaque
data:
  foo: bar
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: twistlock-service
  namespace: twistlock
secrets:
- name: twistlock-secrets
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: twistlock-defender-ds
  namespace: twistlock
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: twistlock-defender
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/twistlock-defender: unconfined
      labels:
        app: twistlock-defender
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: twistlock-service
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: twistlock-defender
        image: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: defender
  namespace: twistlock
  labels:
    app: twistlock-defender
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 9998
  selector:
    app: twistlock-defender
```

*Note: the empty documents are part of the YAML generated by the vendor's API*

Now consider having a patch that needs to be applied only to the kind: DaemonSet resource:

```yaml
# our patch
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: twistlock-defender-ds
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
```

What is the cleanest way of merging these items in Ansible into a single YAML document?

I was able to get two variables, one containing all of the resources except the DaemonSet, and another with the "patched" DeamonSet resource.

```yaml
- name: Load defender YAML into list of dicts
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('file', VENDOR_GENERATED_YAML.yml) | from_yaml_all | list | difference(empty_list)}}"
  register: defender_yaml

- name: Register Defender YAML with the exception of the DaemonSet
  debug:
    msg: " {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ defender_yaml.msg }}"
  when: "'twistlock-defender-ds' not in item.metadata.name"
  register: defender_yaml_nods

- name: Merge and register Defender DaemonSet YAML with our patch
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'defender_yaml_patch.yml') | from_yaml | combine(item, recursive=True) }}"
  loop: "{{ defender_yaml.msg }}"
  when: "'twistlock-defender-ds' in item.metadata.name"
  register: defender_yaml_ds
```

However, now I still have a list of dicts in one resource, and dict in the 2nd resource. Trouble is, the k8s module in Ansible can only accept a single, continuous resource definition.

It seems to me that there should be an "easy" way of doing this in Ansible, and that I might be missing something here. Otherwise, I will simply shell out to `kubectl` and using it to apply a kustomize file combining the 2 YAMLs.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `kustomize` but then I reached the bottom of your question :). That really seems to be the most effective way of patching Kubernetes manifests (because it "knows" about the structure of the manifests, so it can match your patch with the appropriate resource based on name/kind/etc).

Answer (score 0):

Not the really the answer you are looking for, but the best way to solve your particular problem is using the [Prisma Cloud Compute Operator](https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/prisma-cloud-compute-operator).

You will end up doing the following steps:

1. Create twistlock namespace.
2. Create secret, looking like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pcc-credentials
  namespace: twistlock
data:
  accessToken: <base64 encoded access token>
  license: <base64 encoded license key>
  password: <base64 encoded password>
  username: <base64 encoded username>
```

3. Clone operator and apply resources to your cluster:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/prisma-cloud-compute-operator.git
kubectl apply -k prisma-cloud-compute-operator/config/deploy
```

4. Deploy console and defender based on this definition:

```yaml
--- 
apiVersion: pcc.paloaltonetworks.com/v1alpha1
kind: ConsoleDefender
metadata:
  name: pcc-consoledefender
  namespace: twistlock
spec:
  namespace: twistlock
  orchestrator: kubernetes
  version: '21_08_520'
  consoleConfig:
    serviceType: ClusterIP
  defenderConfig:
    docker: false
```